# Why is this Go program only working with odd number of ints sent to channel?

Tags: go, concurrency

We had an assignment in school to fix a go program that had a bug that it didn't print all values sent to the channel. I'm not asking for the solution to that, but I found something weird that I can not explain with my knowledge of Go.

This is the code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    ch := make(chan int)

    go Print(ch)
    for i := 1; i <= 12; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }
    close(ch)
}

func Print(ch <-chan int) {
    for n := range ch{ 
        fmt.Println(n)
    }
}
```

The problem is that the Print routine won't print all integers that are sent on the channel, which I have managed to fix in my solution using a waitgroup. But the weird thing is that the program will print all ints sent to the channel perfectly if the number of ints are even. So I tried to run this program in the Go Playground and it seemed like the program in Go Playground instead would print all ints if the number of ints were odd. Why is this? I am a bit confused about this.

Link to go playground program: https://play.golang.org/p/-BLHvC8RomC

Comment: Pure chance. It does **not** depend on odd/even.

Comment: Can you also add a playground link to _your_ solution? That will help us tell you what went wrong.

Comment: The code you provided outputs 1 to 11, with no numbers missing. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: It should output 12 as well. Read: `while i smaller or equal to 12`

Answer (score 1):

You have to properly synchronize your program:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
)

func main() {
        done := make(chan bool)
        ch := make(chan int)

        go Print(ch, done)
        for i := 1; i <= 12; i++ {
                ch <- i
        }
        done<-true
        <-done
}

func Print(ch chan int, done chan bool) {
        defer func(done chan bool){done<-true}(done)
        for{
                select {
                case <-done:
                        return
                case n := <-ch:
                        fmt.Println(n)
                }
        }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/e_fr2UBeyKA

Comment: this will create a deadlock!

Comment: Indeed! Do you spot the mistake?

Comment: wrap `close(ch)` and `wg.Wait()` in a goroutine `go func() {
  close(ch)
  wg.Wait()
 }()
`

Comment: This will fix the deadlock but only print until eleven. There is still a race condition between closing the channel and printing. Once the channel is closed, the `for` loop in `Print` will terminate.

Comment: Oh that's because we're closing the channel first, we should call wg.Wait() first and then close the channel.

Comment: But then the for loop in the Print function will never terminate ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a consumer-producer concurrency pattern, and one way of implementing it in Go is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

// function that produces i.e. sends to channel
func generate(ch chan int, done chan bool) {
    for i := 1; i <= 12; i++ {
        ch <- i
    }
    done <- true
}

// function that consumes i.e. receives from channel
func print(ch chan int) {
    for i:= range ch {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}

func main() {
    done := make(chan bool)
    // defer close(done)
    ch := make(chan int)
    // defer close(ch)
    go generate(ch, done)
    go print(ch)
    <-done
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

import “time” and add a time.Sleep(50000) after the close.   You have an implicit race, where main is tearing down the program, and your goroutine hasn’t finished.